# I want to rewrite my old URL to new URL without getting redirected

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dynamic, url-rewriting

I have an old URL which is active and working. But I want to have a new URL structure for that exact old content without redirection. Below is my code which I have tried for some rewrite rules. But it's not working for me. Kindly help me out of this.
Thanks in advance

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/https://www.some.com/somelink/somelink2 https://www.some.com/itinerary?itinerary_types=some-package [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

Comment: can you try as 
Redirect 301 //somelink/somelink2 https://www.some.com/itinerary?itinerary_types=some-package

if this not work then you have to use plugin for this cause in somecase the child-urls not redirect by .htaccess